# Does a "null" node in a list count as an item in the list?

Tags: java, linked-list

As part of some coursework I have to write a program that returns the number of nodes in a list. If the list exists but it contains only 1 null node, should the number returned be 0 or 1 ?

Comment: If the value in the node is null then it should return 1. If there are no nodes then return 0.

Comment: Your questions are not very well received on stackoverflow so far as I can see from your profile. Just so you know: If you are getting too many downvotes you will be disallowed to ask further questions. The question you are asking can be checked by yourself if you'd just write a small program and check what comes out which is why you are getting downvoted here.

Comment: I'm pretty lost in my course right now so I seem to ask stupid questions I could have checked myself, except that I don't even have the knowledge in the first place so I wouldn't know where to start checking.

Answer (score 0):

List contains one item even though the one item is null. Hence list count is 1.

You can actually try this out with simple program:

```
    LinkedList lista = new LinkedList();
    lista.add(null);
    System.out.println(lista.size());
```